# Programmatically create a Mockito SpyBean of a given Class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito, spybean

My abstract test needs to create a SpyBean of a defined class within the concrete implementation and I do not want the implementation or the "user" to have to add the `@SpyBean` annotation.

How can I programmatically create a SpyBean of a given Class without using the `@SpyBean` annotation?

Comment: `Mockito.spy(…)` as a first step?

Comment: @knittl but does it create a bean that is known to the dependency injection?

Comment: Yes, if it's used when creating the bean in the Spring test configuration (e.g. `@TestConfiguration` annotated class), but from the question I'm not sure if it solves your problem. Do you want non-abstract test classes to be able to provide the instance that should be a spied on and injected into the Spring context or just to avoid the non-abstract classes to know that a spy is used by the abstract class?